# Angular wiris integration, toolbar is not visible

Tags: angular, wiris

I'm trying to integrate the wiris editor to angular 8, everything seems to be working except the toolbar is not visible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: witch you tool need to  integrate

Comment: @Arvind wiris editor, it  is mathtype editor for visually editing math equations